# How to arrive at the Dirac Equation from Poincaré Algebra?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, dirac-equation, lorentz-symmetry, poincare-symmetry

For the case of Galilean group, the time translation is given by the generator $H$. Hence,
$$\mid\psi(t)\rangle\to \mid\psi(t+s)\rangle =e^{-iHs}\mid\psi(t)\rangle$$ 
Which immediately is the Schrödinger equation,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\mid\psi(t)\rangle=-iH\mid\psi(t)\rangle$$
How to arrive at the Dirac Equation from the Poincaré Algebra/Group? I know it will be much more involved. I am not expecting answers that say how Dirac thought of it or trial and error nonsense.

The necessity for Dirac equation should be visible from the Poincaré Algebra/Group?. How does spin come into the picture?

Comment: The Dirac equation is merely the Schrödinger equation for a special $H$ on a special space (the space of Dirac spinors). I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I was thinking the specialty must be hidden in the Poincare group. How does the Poincare group show that the H is special? What specialties in the Poincare Algebra make it different from the Galilie algebra?

Comment: Naively the Dirac equation tries to establish the relativistic energy-momentum relation with a first order wave equation, doesn't it? It is fair to ask if this leads to a unique equation. I don't think it does, isn't Dirac just using the minimal representation? And with this the experimentalists ends his foam-hand waving.

Comment: From a deleted answer: Here's Wigner and Bargmann's paper on how to get all possible relativistic wave equations from the Poincaré group: http://www.pnas.org/content/34/5/211.full.pdf

Comment: That actually is a very good question. Dirac didn't do it that way. In terms of the Poincaré algebra one can make sense of the relation $P^2=m^2$ in the universal envelopping algebra. Then as CuriousOne says, this is not a "linear" relation and Dirac found a linear condition that implies this one. I am working on an idea at the moment and if I get something, I'll answer your question

Comment: @Noix07 I actually found a complicated way to do it. Lorentz group comes from the minkowski metric using which one can construct Clifford algebras from there you get all the standard spin, etc and Dirac operator also comes up similarly. I am not satisfied with this. I have not yet arrived at the Dirac equation directly from Poinare group. An answer would be helpful.

Comment: @bgr95 Actually $p^{\mu}$ can be considered either as a 4-vector coming from $\frac{d}{d \tau} x^{\mu}$ which naturally belongs to the Minkowski space. But as the generators of translations, i.e. in the Lie algebra we continue to think that there is that Minkowski metric. Is it an intrinsic structure of the Poincaré algebra? If so then one can consider the Clifford algebra associated to the Poincaré algebra??

Answer (score 6):

First, note that on the Hilbert space of physical states is realized the projective representations of the Poincare group, precisely, the representations "up to the sign". This can be incorporated automatically by enlarging the Poincare group up to its universal covering group, which is $ISL(2,C)$.

Here is the general statement which is the point: one-particle representations of the $ISL(2,C)$ with non-zero mass $m$ and a spin $s$ are realized by the spinor tensors $
\psi_{a_{1}...a_{n}\dot{b}_{1}...\dot{b}_{m}}, \ \frac{m+n}{2}=s$ satisfying the equations
$$
\tag 1
\begin{cases}(\partial^{2}+m^{2})\psi_{a_{1}...a_{n}\dot{b}_{1}...\dot{b}_{m}} = 0, \\ \partial^{a\dot{b}}\psi_{aa_{1}...a_{n-1}\dot{b}\dot{b}_{1}...\dot{b}_{m-1}}= 0, \quad \partial^{a\dot{b}} \equiv \partial^{\mu}\sigma_{\mu}^{a\dot{b}}, \ \ \text{for } A,B> 1  \end{cases}
$$ 
As the reminder, the undotted indices correspond to the $SL(2,C)$ group (which is the universal covering group for the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)_{\uparrow}$) transformation $N$, while the dotted indices correspond to the complex conjugated transformation $N^{*}$. Finally, $\sigma_{\mu} \equiv (1, \sigma)$, with $\sigma$ being the three Pauli matrices.

You should understand $(1)$ as the equations defining $\psi$ as the function corresponding to the representation on which two Poincare's group Casimir's operators $\hat{P}^{2}$ (translation/4-momentum squared) and $\hat{W}^{2}$ (Pauli-Lubanski squared) have the values $m^{2}$ and $-m^{2}s(s+1)$ correspondingly. This can be shown by expressing these Casimir's invariants in terms of the spinor tensors objects.

Let's denote the tensor $\psi_{a_{1}...a_{n}\dot{b}_{1}...\dot{b}_{m}}$ by the representation $\left( \frac{n}{2},\frac{m}{2}\right)$ of the $SL(2,C)$ group to which it corresponds. For the spin one half, from the previous statements we have that both of the representations $\left( \frac{1}{2},0\right)$ and $\left( 0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ are valid; they're given by the two-component spinors. But corresponding equations, which are simply the Klein-Gordon equations, are far from the Dirac equation... So what's the another point?

In fact, neither $\left( \frac{1}{2}, 0\right)$ nor $\left(0,\frac{1}{2} \right)$ describes the theory which is invariant under $P-,T-,C-$ discrete symmetries separately; from this in particular follows that it's impossible to construct the EM interaction theory of these representations with the static interaction law coinciding with the Coulomb law.

In order to get invariant theory, we need to take the direct sum
$$
\tag 2 \left( \frac{1}{2},0\right) \oplus \left( 0,\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
of these representations.

But this direct sum is of course not irreducible representation. In order to make it irreducible (and simultaneously $P-,T-,C-$ invariant), we need to construct a poincare- and $P-,T-,C-$covariant operator which allocates the irreducible representation when acting on the direct sum $(2)$. It's not hard to construct such operator (assuming you can derive $(1)$), and it turns out that it coincides with the Dirac equation operator.

Similar story is true when we consider photons and gravitons. In fact, the massless representations of the Poincare group are characterized by the helicity value, which is the operator's $\hat{h} = \frac{\hat{\mathbf{W}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf P}}{|\hat{\mathbf P}|}$ value, and physically is the projection of the total angular momentum on the direction of motion. Again, the representations with separate values of helicity (say, 1, or -1) are not $P-,T-,C-$invariant. In order to have invariant theory, it's necessary again to take the direct sum, but now without any projectors. In the case of the photons we'll arrive to Maxwell equations on the strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$, while in the case of the gravitons we'll arrive to equations on the linearized source-free general relativity Weyl tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you provide me some reference where I can find the details.

Comment: @bgr95 : I only have the reference on russian.