# Why don't we calculate spin number in classical mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

We all know classical mechanics deal with bigger objects and
quantum mechanics deal with very tiny particles.

I hear spin number in quantum mechanics, but I don't see anything
like that in classic mechanics.

Why don't we calculate spin number in classical mechanics?

Comment: Are you asking about revolution versus rotation of planets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking:
Classical mechanics is the approximation of quantum mechanics
in the limit of $\hbar \to 0$ (where $\hbar$ is [Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)).

In quantum mechanics the [electron's spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Pauli_matrices) is given by
$$\vec{S}=\frac{1}{2}\hbar\vec{\sigma}.$$
where $\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, $\sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices.

The classical limit (for $\hbar \to 0$) of this is obviously:
$\vec{S}=\vec{0}$.
That means: There is no spin in classical mechanics.
Spin is an entirely quantum mechanical phenomenon.

Comment: But you could say the same thing for momentum $P=-i\hbar D$ as $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. I don't think this argument applies.

Comment: @RyderRude That is a different situation.
You have $P=-i\hbar D=\hbar k=h/\lambda \to 0 / 0$
as $h\to 0$ and $\lambda\to 0$ in the classical limit.
So you cannot conclude $P\to 0$.

Comment: Still it is possible to replace the Spin commutators with Poisson brackets to get a classical theory, classical in the sense that all the spin projections are simultaneously well defined. See :https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/285314/50583 . This classical theory describes the expected value evolution of quantum spin, just like every other classical theory describes the expected value evolution of a quantum theory.